# Term for phrases that combine abstract and concrete elements

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Is there a term for words that are a combination of abstract and concrete nouns?

For example: Mental floss, Pipe dream, Relational glue

Comment: These are all [Metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf). Metaphors always combine something concrete and sensible (like floss or pipes or glue) with something abstract and nonsensory (like minds or dreams or relations), in order to allow us to pretend we understand the abstractions.

Answer (score 3):

See [reifying](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reifying) at Merriam Webster. The process is called **Reification**. It is defined as

> to consider or represent (something abstract) as a material or concrete thing :  to give definite content and form to (a concept or idea)

Read [this Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(fallacy)). It is pretty elaborate. It explains different constructs.

You'll also find [concretism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concretism) to be interesting which seems to define what you're looking for, though all definitions I found are related to poetry.